# Example: Debugging in OMNeT++

Tags: c++, network-programming, omnet++

I know, this may be a lot to ask, but can anyone help me debug this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;


class Node : public cSimpleModule
{
  private:
    cMessage *out_msg;

    long no_sent = 0;
    long no_rcvd = 0;
    cOutVector rcvdRecord;
    cLongHistogram Statistics;

  public:
    Node();
    virtual ~Node();

  protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
    virtual void finish() override;
};

Define_Module(Node);

Node::Node()
{
    out_msg = nullptr;
}

Node::~Node()
{
    delete out_msg;
}

void Node::initialize()
{
    out_msg = nullptr;

    if (strcmp("sender", getName()) == 0) {
        EV << "Scheduling first send to t=5.0s\n";
        scheduleAt(5.0, out_msg);
        out_msg = new cMessage("Sending Message");
    }
}

void Node::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg == out_msg) {
        EV << "Sending message to receiver\n";
        send(out_msg, "out");
        out_msg = nullptr;
        no_sent++;

        simtime_t delay = par("delayTime");
        scheduleAt(simTime() + delay, out_msg);
    }

        else {
            out_msg = msg;
            no_rcvd++;
            rcvdRecord.record(out_msg);
            Statistics.collect(out_msg); //what's going on here ?
    }
}

void Node::finish()
{
    EV << "Sent:     " << no_sent << endl;
    EV << "Received: " << no_rcvd << endl;
    EV << "Messages sent, mean:   " << Statistics.getMean() << endl;
    EV << "Messages sent, standard deviation: " << Statistics.getStddev() << endl;
    EV << "Messages sent, variance: " << Statistics.getVariance() << endl;
    recordScalar("#sent", no_sent);
    recordScalar("#received", no_rcvd);
    Statistics.recordAs("Message Statistics");
}
```

I get the following error message:

> Exercise2.cc:66:38: error: no matching function for call to
>   'omnetpp::cOutVector::record(omnetpp::cMessage*&)'
>
> Exercise2.cc:67:39: error: no matching function for call to
>   'omnetpp::cLongHistogram::collect(omnetpp::cMessage*&)'

So I really don't know what this is supposed to tell me. Aren't these built-in functions, part of the `cOutVector` or `cLongHistogram` classes respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Aren't these built-in functions, part of the `cOutVector` or
>   `cLongHistogram` classes respectively?

They aren't. Well, `cOutVector` does have a member function named `record`, it just can't take a `cMessage *` as an argument, so that *specific* function *overload* you wanted to use doesn't exist. Same with `cLongHistogram` and `collect`.

Just take a look at the [documentation](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cOutVector.html):

> A cOutVector object can write **doubles** to the output vector file *...*

And, by the way, what exactly do you expect to see as a "histogram of messages"? :D [This comic](https://xkcd.com/26/) comes to my mind...

To record the messages (not into a `cOutVector`), you can enable [event logging](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#cha:eventlog). The resulting file can be visualized in the Sequence Chart tool of the IDE, see: https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part2/#25-visualizing-on-a-sequence-chart

Comment: Or, to record some property (length, kind, a data member, related but separately computed metrics, or similar) of the messages, use the appropriate getter function, or try recording the related variable to acquire and record the interesting metric itself, not simply the message.

Comment: thx, man! - You're right, histogram of messages doesn't make sense at all.. Kinda just trying out things to get used to this tool.